# I am trying to insert the bottom navigation bar which i have created into my main page which is the hunt view but its not working when i run the code

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

This is the main page where I have written the bottom bar navigation code. I have run the code, but the bar does not appear on my home page. It does not give me any errors. which means the code is fine and i just need to call it properly. How do I call the function so it displays across all other pages?

```
import 'package:thehunt/views/hunt/profile_view.dart';
import 'package:thehunt/views/hunt/settings_view.dart';
import 'package:thehunt/views/login_view.dart';

class HuntView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HuntView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomeView();
          } else {
            return AuthView();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



//bottom navigation bar

class BottomNavView extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavView({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavView> createState() => _BottomNavViewState();
}

class _BottomNavViewState extends State<BottomNavView> {
  List views = [
    const HomeView(),
    const CurrentLocationView(),
    const ProfileView(),
    const SettingsView()
  ];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTap(int index) {
    currentIndex = index;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: views[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedFontSize: 0,
        selectedFontSize: 0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 198, 176, 235),
        onTap: onTap,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        elevation: 0,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Home',
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Map',
            icon: Icon(Icons.map),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Settings',
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Profile',
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my home page view where I want the bottom navigation bar to be displayed

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('               Home'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      drawer: const NavigationDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Logged In as: ' + user.email!),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              },
              color: Colors.deepPurple[200],
              child: Text('sign out'),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return const CurrentLocationView();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                color: Colors.deepPurple[200],
                child: const Text('User location')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call BottomNavView in HuntView instead of HomeView as below code

```
class HuntView extends StatelessWidget {
const HuntView({super.key});
 @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return BottomNavView();    <------- call here BottomNavView
      } else {
        return AuthView();
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: It works, thanks, but I cannot see the bottom bar across all the other pages. It disappears when I go to the next page

Comment: Wrap currentIndex = index with setState in your onTap method in HuntView